# How do you remove a halo from a sunset picture in Aurora HDR?

Tags: hdr

I'm trying to make an HDR picture from a sunset taken from a boat. Using the typical settings, I'm getting a sun that looks like this:

[image: Halo around sun]

How do I fix it?

Comment: I added them in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following settings to reduce the sun halo:

1) Turn on alignment:
[image: Turn on auto alignment]

2) Set ghost reduction to medium and pick the darkest picture, the one with the lowest EV and smallest sun.
[image: Pick the darkest picture]

New results:

[image: Better sun picture]